# Make div appear from side of screen using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div that I would like to appear from the side of the screen after the website page has loaded.

So I would be setting this div to be off the screen probably using an absolute position, then once whole page has loaded would like the div to slide into the screen in a nice smooth motion then settle to the right of the centred website.

Comment: at the moment I have not tried anything as I am fairly new to javascript/jquery and cannot find a solution online for this.

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/ZnssH/) - Its not very hard to do it. And there a loads of places to learn this. I would recommend using this as a guide and then look up what it does and how. This is one of **many** ways to do it. You should try to solve the problem yourself and share the code. This is not a site where we will write free code. As this is very minor and I happened to be doing something similar at the time I made a demo for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your website is centered, and you don't know the viewport dimensions of the user. You could detect it with javascript, but i think the better way is to animate position and opacity.

you can then move the div in from the left and in the same time fade it in. The animation looks smooth on small and big windows.

look for jquery.animate().

Better and faster is probably using css transitions and add a class in the $(window).load() function.